# Get XHR resource protected by SSO from AJAX

Tags: ajax, cors, single-sign-on

Basically I have an online API (XHR) protected by SSO (OAuth 2.0 based on Vouch). Upon accessing the API via GET request you get Error 302 and redirect you to login and then if authenticated successfully you back to your API and access the resource securely.

I need to access XHR resource (XML) via AJAX from "https://www.someUrl.com" source - see example below:

```
    $.ajax({
    url: "https://api.someUrl.com/xmlapi",
    dataType: 'xml',
    type: 'GET',
    
    success: function(xmlDoc){
    
    },
    error: function(xmlDoc) {
    console.log('Error: ' + xmlDoc.responseText);
    }
    });
```

If cookie is already there then no error displayed and everything runs smoothly. If cookie not there then I get CORS cross-origin error.

If user not authenticated "https://api.someUrl.com/xmlapi" would normally return 302 (temp redirect). But in the AJAX no re-direction is happening.

Developer tool is dispalying the following popular error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.someUrl.com/xmlapi' from origin 'https://www.someUrl.com' 
has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested 
resource.
```

I tried to update the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' on the server side but its not responding to it. It seems to do with re-direcing in ajax not accepted by the browser although the browser compaining about CORS issue.

Checked in the developer tool under Network, that is what I have:

**General**

```
 Request URL: https://api.someUrl.com/xmlapi
    Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

**Response Headers**

```
content-length: 145
content-type: text/html
date: Mon, 10 May 2021 10:51:09 GMT
location: https://login.someUrl.com/login?

url=https://api.someUrl.com/apixml&vouch-failcount=&X- 
    Vouch-Token=&error=
server: nginx/1.18.0
```

**Request Headers**

```
 :authority: api.someUrl.com
    :method: GET
    :path: /apixml
    :scheme: https
    accept: application/xml, text/xml, */*; q=0.01
    accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
    accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
    origin: https://www.someUrl.com
    referer: https://www.someUrl.com/
    sec-fetch-dest: empty
    sec-fetch-mode: cors
    sec-fetch-site: same-site
```

My setup is something like this:

- From www.XXX access resource on sub-domain api.XXX
- api.XXX redirt to sub-domain login.XXX
- If login sucessfully, redirect back to api.XXX

Above works but when I port it to ajax it doesnt.

The purpose is to get the www.XXX user to authenticate if the ajax code requires access to protect resource such as api.XXX.

Any advice is highly appreciated.

Comment: Is this problem related to this? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSExternalRedirectNotAllowed

Comment: Its seems I have to find a way to capture the OPTION requests (pre-flights) in nginx scope. This need to be done before authorization take place. I have to ind a way to do it. Will post the solution once I find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason I'm experiencing this issue is because the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is completly missing in 302 (re-direct) responses. "curl -v https://api.com.au" helped me quicky see the headers. There was 'location' header but no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'. Hence the browser was giving CORS error right away and ignoring the re-direct. The solution was to add 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' to the 302 response header in NGINX.

That is the config in NGINX that helped resolve the issue.

```
 location @error401 {
            # I added 3 lines below to solve CORS issue for 302 re-direct.
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://www.XXX.com.au" always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, OPTIONS' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
            # redirect to Vouch Proxy for login
            return 302 https://login.XXX.com.au/login?url=$scheme://$http_host$request_uri&vouch-failcount=$auth_resp_failcount&X-Vouch-Token=$auth_resp_jwt&error=$auth_resp_err;
            # you usually *want* to redirect to Vouch running behind the same Nginx config proteced by https
            # but to get started you can just forward the end user to the port that vouch is running on
        }
```